# Using Asset folder variables with Sprout Forms

Tags: assets, plugin-sproutforms

Is it possible to use auto-generated subfolders within an asset field? Each time I've tried, I get errors upon submitting the form that seem unrelated and nothing posts.

I'm just trying to do a simple job application form on our website and I'd like to have the file dumped into the subfolders: `{jobID}\{email}` (`jobID` is passed in as a hidden field), this way I know there won't be any issues uploading files unless the same person applies multiple times to the same position in which I guess I could put a timestamp on there as well.

I've tried those simple variables mentioned above, and I've also tried `{object.jobID}\{object.email}` but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a form with a hidden field and asset field. The hidden field appears before the asset field:

[image]

We'll want to make the email field required because we are using that field in the auto-generated subfolders. (if it is empty it will generate an error)

Place a forward slash in before the folder location of the asset field: `/{jobid}/{email}`

[image]

The `object` variable will not work in the Sprout Forms context. We can use the field handle (`{id}`, `{name}`...) or the `form` object (`{form.id}`, `{form.name}`...) if you want to be more specific.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like the key was just to rearrange the order of my fields and put the others before my assets field.